# How do i disable the inter function from being executed after once it has been called

Tags: javascript

Do I have to disable the start ID or the function and How do i do it.function inter

```
function inter() {
  //something needed to be done
}

function myLoadEvent() {
  var start = document.getElementById('start');
  start.addEventListener('click', inter);
}
```

I used this `document.getElementById("start").disabled = true;`

Comment: Code formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove it in your handler.

```js
var start = document.getElementById('start');
function inter()
{

   //something needed to be done
   console.log('done');
   start.removeEventListener('click', inter);
}
start.addEventListener('click', inter);
```

```html
<button id='start'>click</button>
```